# How do you save entities with a bidirectional relationship from the non-owning side?

Tags: jpa, mapping

What is the best way to represent the below tables with a bidirectional relationship where `nodes` is the owning side using Spring Data/JPA? I want to be able to save `nodes` with `node_node` and have `node_node` be saved.

**nodes** table

- id

**node_node** table

- node_id_1
- node_id_2

Here is what I have so far. A bidirectional relationship with `NodeNode` being the owning side which means when I create, update or delete an element in either `parents` or `children` of `Node`, it won't be persisted. When I update `Node` by adding to `parent` or `children`, it seems to working but when I update by removing, it doesn't work. I would need to save through `NodeNode` since it is the owning side but that is too much of a hassle since it will require a save to `Node` and `NodeNode`.

```
public class Node {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<NodeNode> parents;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<NodeNode> children;

}

public class NodeNode {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id_1")
    private Node parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id_2")
    private Node child;

}
```

The goal is to be able to save a `Node` with any changes to `Node.parents` or `Node.children` and have the `NodeNode` be saved too.

Comment: What does "best" mean? Without specifying that it is opinion based.

Comment: @JensSchauder I'd like to what the standard way of implementing it. The way I requested it to work is how I'd want to implement it but it may not be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to replace the `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` with `ManyToMany` relationships, and using `Node` instead of referencing `NodeNode`.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH,  CascadeType.DETACH })
@JoinTable(name = "node_node", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "node_id_1"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "node_id_2"))
private Set<Node> children;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "children")
private Set<Node> parents;
```